# Javascript remove all leading and trailing junk characters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have strings like

```
"&% , USEFUL DATA ^$^@&#!*, USEFUL DATA *%@^#,,,   "
```

Need it cleaned like:

```
"USEFUL DATA   ^$^@&#!*,  USEFUL DATA"
```

Do we have any standard library function in Javascript to do that (We have it in python)?

Ex: `trim(str, "!@#$%^^&*(), ")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replace(/^\W+|\W+$/g, "");
```

`\W` will match all the non-word characters.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bV4fL5/2)

To remove specific character use character class:

```
str = str.replace(/^[@#$%^&*(), ]+|[@#$%^&*(), ]+$/g, "");
```

Comment: Based on his example (although a misleading title), he wants to remove the junk at the front too.

Comment: Yes trailing word mislead me. I edited answer to remove those chars from front also.

Comment: Just a side note - people using this for languages other than English should be careful because it removes not just junk but also legitimate characters - for example, try "él cayó" in Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex `replace`:

```js
var s = "&% , USEFUL DATA ^$^@&#!*, USEFUL DATA *%@^#,,, ";
document.write(s.replace(/^\W+|\W+$/g, '') + "<br/>");
// or
document.write(s.replace(/^[^\w]+|[^\w]+$/g, ''));
```

The pattern `^\W+|\W+$` will remove all "special" characters from both beginning and end of the string. Note that `\W` matches every character that is not in the `[A-Za-z0-9_]` class, and `\w` matches those characters. `[^\w]` is a negated character class where `^` means *not*, and then you can add more characters/shorthand classes that you want to keep.